# Arranging groups with no overlap

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have 125 distinguishable objects, and we want to form 775 groups of 5 among these objects such that every object is grouped with each other object exactly once (in other word, for every pair of objects, there is exactly one group that contains both those objects). Determine a way to do this.

Edit: Could anyone solve following "related cases":

1. Given 72 objects, we want to form 8 groups of 9 and 81 groups of 8, so that each object is grouped with each other object exactly once. Is this possible? If so, how?
2. Given 72 objects, we want to form 9 groups of 8 and 64 groups of 9, so that each object is grouped with each other object exactly once. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Take the $775$ lines with $5$ points each in $(\mathbb Z/(5))^3$. Note that any two points define exactly one such line.

Comment: can you elaborate on how this work?

Comment: also, what is $(\mathbb{Z}/(5))^3$?

Comment: Triples of integers mod $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify your $125$ objects with the set $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^3$, which is the set of triples of integers modulo $5$. Think of these triples as vectors; they can be added to each other coordinatewise $\pmod 5$, and scaled by elements of $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$. For example,
$$
(3,2,3)+(2,1,4)=(0,3,2),\qquad 3\cdot (1,2,3)=(3,1,4).
$$
Given two such vectors $x$ and $y$, define the line through $x$ and $y$ to be the following set of five vectors:
$$
\{x+t\cdot (y-x): t\in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z\}
$$
(Note the similarities to normal geometry; if $x,y$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ instead of $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^3$, then the line through $x$ and $y$ is $\{x+t(y-x): t\in \mathbb R\}$).

Every unordered pair of vectors determines a line. Furthermore, for each line, there are exactly $\binom{5}2$ ways to choose a pair of points on that line, and each pair will generate the same line using the above formula. It follows that the number of lines of this form is equal to
$$
\binom{125}2\Big/\binom{5}2=775
$$
These set of lines therefore satisfy your conditions.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! do you have insight into my related questions?